# How to fetch data from an object using ngfor in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to access price data inside space array which is inside an Object

[image: Response]

```
 this.apartmentService.customPackage(this.uid, this.client, this.access_token).subscribe(user => {
      this.packages = user;
      console.log(this.packages);
      
    })
  }
```

Template File

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of packages?.essential_interiors.space.name | keyvalue">
  <li class="list-group-item">{{item.value}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

But i am not able to fetch particular space from this reponse

any lead would be helpful

Comment: what do u want to do in html ? key value is used for object you have array. If you want to just write price then take loop in space array object and get price with item.price

Comment: could you please provide a stackblitz/JSfiddle or whatever workable demo and tell us how it behaves and how it should behave? That would really be very helpful :)

Comment: Please *ngFor="let item of packages"

Answer (score 1):

You should to delete name from the foreach like:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of packages?.essential_interiors.space">
 <li class="list-group-item">{{item.price}}</li>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: It should be {{item.name}} or {{item.price}}

Comment: I forgot to edit this line cuz the first were in ngFor

Answer (score 0):

`KeyValuePipe` transforms only Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.

But in your case, you have an array `space`.

You simply should itarate `*ngFor="let item of packages?.essential_interiors.space"`

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of packages?.essential_interiors.space">
  <li class="list-group-item">{{item.price}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

WORKING EXAMPLE:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfwcio?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Check below thing and let me know what is output display please

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of packages; let i = index">
    {{i}} {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try like this item.essential_interiors.space.name directly in your li tag.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of packages">
  <li class="list-group-item">{{item.essential_interiors.space.name}}</li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I tried this also but it is printing nothing

Comment: @Shuvo, you should not post comments as answers, I understand you don't have enough reputation points to comment but putting them as answers is wrong. Please refrain from doing that.